# How to Ctrl/Cmd + F on github again

Tags: github

Github recently added its own behavior that overrides CMD+F for text searching on a page. Unfortunately instead of text searching the page, it name searches files by name. How does one disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I could not recreate what you mentioned, but I think I have some kind of memory of this happening at one point.  Perhaps they have reverted this feature for now?

Regardless, if your browser's normal search function is what you want and this is being captured, and prevent / customised by the page then you can normally access it from the menu items.  For example using a Brave browser, if you go to `Edit > Find > Find` you can search the page text as normal.